# Files not found in JAR FIle

Tags: spring, spring-boot, file, download

I am trying to find a folder containning PDF's . Everything works when the backend and frontent is not a Jar file.
My question is how do you locate files ,if it is in a JAR, all I am recieving is a file not found exception

Tried adding the file to my resources folder but still nothing.
What am I missing?

[image: Example of my code and where the folders are save]

Comment: You cannot as those aren't files in the sense of a `java.util.File`. A `java.util.File` needs to be a physical resource on the filesystem. When it is inside a jar file it isn't a physical resource anymore. Instead you need to read it as an inputstream.

Comment: In the future, please do not use images of code, paste the code directly into your question.  Use this [document](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a guide.  It makes it easier on those attempting to assist.

Comment: @M.Deinum how do I locate the file when it is in JAR form, the I can add it as a input stream

Comment: @lane.maxwell Appologies, thanks for the doc

Comment: @ChrisJnrPotgieter see the answer below, one of them returns an inputstream :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished in a number of ways, here are a couple:

```
// get the resources as a URL
URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(
    "static/test/TrainingDocuments/SuperUser/2/PartnerInformation/PartnerInformation.pdf");

// get the resource as a classPathResource
ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource(
    "static/test/TrainingDocuments/SuperUser/2/PartnerInformation/PartnerInformation.pdf");

// get the resource directly as a stream
InputStream resourceAsStream = getClass().getClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream("static/test/TrainingDocuments/SuperUser/2/PartnerInformation/PartnerInformation.pdf");
```

Comment: I keep recieving a 404

Comment: A 404 is completely unrelated to your question and means that the URL you are hitting doesn't match any of the controller endpoints that you've defined.